# Distinct in hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, distinct

I want to use DISTINCT in my hive query.So query looks like

```
Insert overwrite table tablename select distinct a.id AS ID , a.id AS SID from a left join b on a.id = b.id;
```

So in above query I want to insert same value for two different column.With DISTINCT query doesn't work ,otherwise it works.

Comment: whats the output you are getting and how deviated is it from your expectation

Comment: Try using Group By instead of Distinct... Hope this helps you...